# How to connect Flutter App to github csv repository?

Tags: flutter, csv, dart, dart-pub

For displaying updated data i would like to connect to a remote github `csv` repo hosted here: http://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv

How can this be achieved? I did not found any library to work.

Answer (score 0):

`csv` file is pure text, simple format sheet. You can use Okio download it to local, then read it as a txt file.

The first line of `csv` file indicate all clomuns, splite by symbol `,`; from the second is the real data, order as the column shown in first line.

So, read the file by line, then splite each line string by symbol `,`, you can get the data you want.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. The thing is that I do not want to download any file. I want the connection to be directly from the repository.

Comment: Same. Connect to the file needs you have to load the file to local (in memory I think, if you don't want to save it as file). Since it's a raw file in server, there is not way to give you a API to deal with data directly.

Comment: Oh, okay. Could you please example me with a code snippet? I have around 2 hours of Dart programming.